# Doctrine - Make Multiple Entities From One Table

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, refactoring

I am currently working on a **huge** refactoring project. We have taken over a classic PHP/MySQL project, where most code is procedural, duplicated, and there is very little hint of an architecture.

I am planning on using Doctrine to handle our Data Access, and have all of my tables mapped to entities. **However**, our MySQL tables are largely messed up.

The table I am currently working with has over 40 columns, and is not normalized by any means. A quick example of what we have:

#### Brand

```
id
name
poNumber
orderConfirmationEmail <---- these should go into a BrandConfirmations entity
shippingConfirmationEmail <-----
bill_address <---- these should go into a BrandAddress entity
bill_address2 <-----
city          <------
.
.
.
```

Ideally, what I would like to have is for Doctrine to pull out the fields that reference different Entities, and actually put them into those Entities. So for instance id, name, and poNumber would get pulled out into a **Brand** entity. orderConfirmationEmail and shippingConfirmationEmail would get pulled out into a BrandNotification entity. Next, bill_address, and the rest of the address fields would get pulled out into a BrandBillAddress entity. Is there a way to configure Doctrine to split the table into these models for me, or do I have to custom write code myself that would do that?

If I do have to write the code to split this table myself, do you have any resources or advice that tackle a similar issue? I haven't been able to find many yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Doctrine 2 supports what they call embeddables:  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html.  It may solve some of your problems.  However,  it requires D2.5+.  Currently, S2 uses Doctrine 2.4.  You could experiment with using the very latest doctrine.

What you can do is make your domain models (entities) act as though you had value objects.  So $brand->getOrderConfirmation() would actually return an order confirmation object.  You have to do some messing around to keep everything mapped to one table and you might be limited on some of your queries but it's not that hard. The advantage is that the rest of your new applications deals with proper normalized objects. It's only the internal persistence code that needs to get messy.

There are quite a few links on this approach.  Here is one: http://russellscottwalker.blogspot.com/2013/11/entities-vs-value-objects-and-doctrine-2.html

Your best bet of course is to refactor your database schema.  I like to do kind of a raw dump of the original database into a yaml file with the desired object nesting.  I then load the yaml file into the new schema.  If you are really lucky then you might even be able to create new views for your existing application which will allow it to keep working in parallel with your new application.

Comment: I am actually using Doctrine standalone at the moment, so I could try grabbing the newer one. While I would love to do the db refactor, it's not too much of an option at the moment. We are trying to get the codebase at a workable level, then get to the database once the code is workable. I would be interested in hearing more about the YAML approach you use though for the future when we do refactor the db.